# How to force power off a VM in vCenter web console?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

When right click a VM in the vCenter web console I only get the option to "**Shut Down Guest OS**".

When I connect directly to the host and look at the VM I have both options to
"**Power Off**" and "**Shut Down Guest**"

Comment: Please specify the version of VMware you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vSphere Web Client provides several options.

Maybe you don't have permissions? Or perhaps this is a browser compatibility issue?

[image]

Comment: I found it under "All vCenter Actions". I think the particular section of the vCenter UI I was looking at didn't have that option.